# Calculate distribution of median statistic of a random sample of size 11 from uniform(0,1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Okay, so firstly is there a difference between "median distribution" and the median?

Here's my idea of tackling this problem.  I know that the median of a distribution is a value m s.t. $P(X\leq m) \geq 1/2$ and $P(X\geq m) \geq 1/2$.  Since we are looking at the uniform distribution which is continuous, we just need to make sure we have an m that satisfied the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{m} 1 dx=\int_{m}^{\infty} 1 dx=1/2$$,

right?  And to do this would we start off by taking the derivative?  I guess if you do that, you get the 1/2 becoming 0 and 1dx equalling 1dx which doesn't make any sense...  Am I thinking in the right approach and if not, what needs to be changed?

Comment: What are the limits on the outcomes of a uniform random variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "outcomes"?  I mean a uniform(0,1) in our case is just 1 in the interval [0,1].

Comment: Right. So if it's in the interval [0,1], why are you using limits on your integrals that are outside of that interval?

Comment: Okay, so the integrals would just changed from 0 to 1.... but how does that make any sense if we are still using the above relationship?  Please elaborate.  I'm getting quite confused.

Comment: Well, if you use $0$ as the lower limit on your first integral and 1 as the upper limit on your second integral, you will find $m = {{1} \over {2}}.$ That's the median of the uniform distribution. Next would be to think about the question in your title. Yes, there is a difference between the median of a random variable and the distribution of a median statistic.

Comment: where would the size 11 fit into all this?

Comment: Now you are talking about the distribution of a sample median. This is a much more difficult question. For a sample of size 11, the median is the 6th order statistic. Look up order statistics on Wikipedia and you will find a section detailing the distribution of the order statistics of a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If $U_{(k)}$ is the $k$th smallest order statistic then the median of a sample of size 11 is given by $U_{(6)}.$ From the Wikipedia entry on order statistics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) you will find the order statistics when taking a sample of size $n$ from a uniform distribution have beta distributions.

$$U_{(k)} \sim \mathrm{beta}(k,n+1-k) $$

So $U_{(6)} \sim \mathrm{beta}(6,6),$ with an expected value of ${{1} \over {2}}.$